# Multiprocessing Python Sampling Distribution Simulation (no interdependence between function calls)

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, sample

I have a function that samples a large numpy array and returns a statistic. This statistic needs to be calculated many times (>20000) from the same data, with the result of each sample stored in a numpy array.

It would be nice to run multiple samples simultaneously, making use of multiple processes.

I looked into the multiprocessing module and read some tutorials on how to use it, but they all assume some interdependence between the workers or at least that each invocation of the function uses different arguments. In my case, the function is to be called with the same arguments every time, and is acting on the same data, so a map() operation does not make sense. The order of completion of each invocation is irrelevant. The only difference in the results of each invocation is due to the random nature of the sampling.

I feel like this should be easy, but all the examples of multiprocessing in Python are very complicated and seem beyond what is necessary for my application.

Comment: with numpy 1.9 you can use the threading module to draw random numbers in parallel, but you need to create a new random state per thread. Older numpys than 1.9 unfortunately use the GIL during random number generation and will not profit from threading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use `map()`. Take a look at using a `Pool` like this:

```
import concurrent.futures 

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=N) as executor:
    ans = executor.map(your_func, [your_arguments] * n_trials)
```

I believe that `concurrent.futures` here is going to be optimal, because it intelligently handles chunking up work across workers. If there's some performance issue with having >20000 copies of your arguments in memory, you can use a generator to lazily give them to the pool, like this:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=N) as executor:
    ans = executor.map(your_func, (your_arguments for _ in range(n_trials)))
```

Note that you should always use processes rather than threads for CPU-bound work, since [thread-based parallelism doesn't work in the standard Python implementation](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf).